# prohibit :update in cancan conflicting with :edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

**CanCanCan version 3.4.0**

Similar issue on [github](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/832)

I have a project with a lot of permissions, for example based on user roles: If a user is staff, he can :edit but not :update, just defined by something like `can [:update], project if user.staff?`.

So far, so good.

Now i want to restrict all users to read-only when project is locked. My idea was to do something like

```
 cannot %i[update update_extra_costs], Project, locked?: true
```

at the end of the Ability Model.

The **problem** is that, in terms of [docs](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/define_check_abilities.md#can-actions), `:update` and `:edit` are coupled for simplicity. If I now do the `cannot :update`, it also restricts the `:edit`!

But most users should be able to see the form (read-only!) and not to be able do a `:update`

As a workaround I tried something like a

```
if can? :edit, Project #=> only if a can? is defined above
  cannot [:update], Project, locked?: true
  can [:edit], Project
end
```

The `can` after the `cannot` did the trick that `edit` was allowed but the `update` not! But this was not the soulution because it would allow all users to see the edit view! So i tried to wrap this in the if, but it didn't work, because `can?` doesn't work inside the Ability Model.

**Questions**

How to do things like this properly?

Is there a way to unlink `:edit` and `:update` so that a `cannot :update` would not affect the `:edit`

Comment: I would look into Pundit instead - you're reaching the level of complexity where CanCanCan is just going to be a royal pain in the backside.

Comment: I am trying to understand why a user would need the ability to "edit" in a non functional manner? What good is a form that can't be submitted?

Comment: @engineersmnky good question, we discussed it on [GitHub](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/832). See my last comment there. In short: In one project there are read-only views built with a form, by disabled:true and :update action forbidden.

Comment: I am more inclined to agree with [This Comment](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/832#issuecomment-1713322262) using a form is a bastardization of the edit and should be converted to a `show` or other display view.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, for new apps what you are saying, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it on model-level, not by cancan. Now there is a `.locked?` method on the model that decides if a update is possible.